# How can I install Asp.Net on vs2015 after already installing vs2015 ？

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have already installed visual studio 2015 before, but I didn't choose the asp.net option at that time.

But now, I want to install asp.net on it.

I know that vs2017 has a vs_install.exe. When you forget to choose some options at the first installing time, you can add them later through vs_install.exe.

Does vs2015 also have the vs_install.exe? If not , how can I install asp.net on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows 10, go to Settings, Apps, Apps & Features, find Visual Studio, and click Modify. This will launch the Visual Studio setup program which allows you to add and remove features.

In earlier versions of Windows you'd go to Control Panel + Add/Remove Programs.